# Получить время в пути с учётом пробок

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, карты, yandexmapkit

Хочется написать приложение для Android напоминающее выходить из дома заранее если на дорогах большие пробки. Для этого нужно как-то узнавать время в пути от дома до работы с учётом пробок. Яндек Карты умеют определять это время. Ещё у них вроде есть API для работы с картами. После беглого просмотра документации сложилось ощунение, что это API в первую очередь презназначено для отрисовки карт. А есть ли в нём функция позволяющая узнать время в пути от точки A до точки B с учётом пробок, не открывая карту? Просто передаёшь две точки и получаешь цифру. Может быть есть похожая функция в API от других поставщиков информации о пробках?

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/router-docpage/

Answer (score 1):

В API Яндекс.Карт это [можно сделать](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_data_access), но [условия использования](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage?from=so) требуют отображать карту.

Есть ещё [Яндекс.Маршрутизация](https://tech.yandex.ru/routing/), которая позволяет получать время в пути через HTTP-запрос, но этот сервис доступен только на коммерческой основе.